# keep format of text in cell in html body

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have just simple question:

in emailSender.Cells(2, 5) there is stored text i want to use in html body of email, but i need to keep exact formatting as it is in this cell, how could I do it?

```
With MItem
        .To = EmailAddr
        .Subject = Subj
            Do While j <= lastRow
                Set searchResult3 = report.Columns(1).Find(tickets.Cells(j, i), LookIn:=xlValues)
                .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "<tr>" & "<td width=""120"">" & tickets.Cells(j, i) & "</td>" & "<td width=""250"">" & searchResult3.Offset(0, 3) & "</td>" & "</tr>"
                j = j + 1
            Loop
        .HTMLBody = emailSender.Cells(2, 5) & "<table border=""1"" bordercolor=black style=""border-collapse: collapse"">" & .HTMLBody & "</table>" & "<br>" & signature
        .Display
     End With
```

Thank you for help :)

Comment: format cell as TEXT or prefix everything in cell with a single quote `'`

Comment: it didnt help anyhow :) some text in this cell is bold, some not and in html body I need it will look same as in that cell

Comment: so you want to evaluate the HTML????

Comment: yes, i think it could be a way.. lets say that text in this cell emailSender.Cells(2, 5) is "Arial" and size 10, so when I use this .HTMLBody = emailSender.Cells(2, 5).... I need it will use Arial and size 10, not the default of Outlook

Comment: oh that is nearly if not impossible :P

Answer (score 0):

I googled "excel vba convert cell to html" and the first result that came up is a complete solution.

Flicking through this code, i can see that it does bold, italic, underline, and the font color. You should be able to easily adapt the font color code to do font size too if that is something that you require.

```
Function fnConvert2HTML(myCell As Range) As String
Dim bldTagOn, itlTagOn, ulnTagOn, colTagOn As Boolean
Dim i, chrCount As Integer
Dim chrCol, chrLastCol, htmlTxt As String

bldTagOn = False
itlTagOn = False
ulnTagOn = False
colTagOn = False
chrCol = "NONE"
htmlTxt = "<html>"
chrCount = myCell.Characters.Count

For i = 1 To chrCount
    With myCell.Characters(i, 1)
        If (.Font.Color) Then
            chrCol = fnGetCol(.Font.Color)
            If Not colTagOn Then
                htmlTxt = htmlTxt & "<font color=#" & chrCol & ">"
                colTagOn = True
            Else
                If chrCol <> chrLastCol Then htmlTxt = htmlTxt & "</font><font color=#" & chrCol & ">"
            End If
        Else
            chrCol = "NONE"
            If colTagOn Then
                htmlTxt = htmlTxt & "</font>"
                colTagOn = False
            End If
        End If
        chrLastCol = chrCol

        If .Font.Bold = True Then
            If Not bldTagOn Then
                htmlTxt = htmlTxt & "<b>"
                bldTagOn = True
            End If
        Else
            If bldTagOn Then
                htmlTxt = htmlTxt & "</b>"
                bldTagOn = False
            End If
        End If

        If .Font.Italic = True Then
            If Not itlTagOn Then
                htmlTxt = htmlTxt & "<i>"
                itlTagOn = True
            End If
        Else
            If itlTagOn Then
                htmlTxt = htmlTxt & "</i>"
                itlTagOn = False
            End If
        End If

        If .Font.Underline > 0 Then
            If Not ulnTagOn Then
                htmlTxt = htmlTxt & "<u>"
                ulnTagOn = True
            End If
        Else
            If ulnTagOn Then
                htmlTxt = htmlTxt & "</u>"
                ulnTagOn = False
            End If
        End If

        If (Asc(.Text) = 10) Then
            htmlTxt = htmlTxt & "<br>"
        Else
            htmlTxt = htmlTxt & .Text
        End If
    End With
Next

If colTagOn Then
    htmlTxt = htmlTxt & "</font>"
    colTagOn = False
End If
If bldTagOn Then
    htmlTxt = htmlTxt & "</b>"
    bldTagOn = False
End If
If itlTagOn Then
    htmlTxt = htmlTxt & "</i>"
    itlTagOn = False
End If
If ulnTagOn Then
    htmlTxt = htmlTxt & "</u>"
    ulnTagOn = False
End If
htmlTxt = htmlTxt & "</html>"
fnConvert2HTML = htmlTxt
End Function

Function fnGetCol(strCol As String) As String   
Dim rVal, gVal, bVal As String
strCol = Right("000000" & Hex(strCol), 6)
bVal = Left(strCol, 2)
gVal = Mid(strCol, 3, 2)
rVal = Right(strCol, 2)
fnGetCol = rVal & gVal & bVal
End Function
```

However, next time try google so you can at least say "i have tried x,y,z way of doing it".

Please note that this code is not mine.

Link: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/626a351a-de17-4389-9ad6-a2be20ce2fd9/convert-contents-of-a-formatted-excel-cell-to-html-format?forum=isvvba